# code that shuffles string not integer

Tags: c++, shuffle

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int cards[52];
    srand(time(0));

    for ( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ) {
        cards[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ) {
        int index = rand() % 52;
        int tmp = cards[i];
        cards[i] = cards[index];
        cards[index] = tmp;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ) {
        cout << cards[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hi everyone, this code generate random number 1-52. Is there a way to shuffle string for example string ("nick", "john", "mike");
and generate these names randomly each time I run the program.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a random number to index into the array of strings.

Comment: just a heads up rand() % 52; is numbers 0-51 if you want 1-52 use rand() % 52 +1;

Comment: Do you want to ***generate*** names or simply _randomly select_ from a predetermined list?

Answer (score 1):

Storing multiple objects can be done with `std::array` or `std::vector` where the first is statically sized while the latter can grow dynamically. Shuffling a collection of elements (with random iterators) can be done with [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/shuffle):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("nick");
    v.push_back("john");
    v.push_back("mike");
    std::mt19937_64 gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);
    for(std::size_t i{}; i < v.size(); ++i) std::cout << v[i] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To shuffle strings, you can use the exact same code that you have now.

You want to be able to change the number of items, so replace int cards[52] with a vector. Also rename it "indexes":

```
std::vector<int> indexes;
```

Resize it when you start the program, assuming you have a vector "names":

```
int main()
{
    int n = names.size();

    indexes.resize(n);
```

And number it from zero up, not from 1:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        indexes[i] = i;
```

Shuffle the "n" ints:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    int index = rand() % n;
    int tmp = indexes[i];
    indexes[i] = indexes[index];
    indexes[index] = tmp;
}
```

Assuming the strings are in an array or vector "names", you can now use the randomized indexes to cycle through them:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    cout << names[indexes[i]] << " ";

cout << endl;
```

This code will be much more efficient than trying to shuffle the strings, because it's only moving ints around, not the whole strings. You could also save several "sortings" separately, and have them all refer back to the same data.

Comment: "*This code will be much more efficient than trying to shuffle the strings.*" This is part of the truth. If you access the collection only once in the specified random order then it is more efficient to use randomized indices on the original data. If you'll access the shuffled data more than once given a specific random order the performance will probably benefit from contiguous storage.

Comment: Well my idea was that you shuffle the indexes once then output the sorted strings once. I think that would in fact be faster. you're only running one copy per string, not a swap, which is three copies.